# Xcode 9 bug : build on device fails with lots of errors, simulator works well

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I encounter a bug on `Xcode 9`, suddenly my project failed building for device, whereas it used to work, and still works well on simulator. It shows lots of non-sense errors, that are mostly related with `UIKit`.

After resetting Derived Data, cleaning project, cleaning build folder, restarting Xcode, restarting computer, I've tried with a blank project with Single View App template. **Same behavior ! So it's not coming from my project.**

Here is a screenshot of the errors when trying to build the new project on device (or building on generic device) :

[image: Xcode errors]

As you can see there is a lot of errors related to `UIKit`, as `Attempting to use the forward class 'X' as superclass of 'Y'`

Does anybody already encounter this horrible bug, and find a solution to fix this corrupted Xcode or have a clue of things to try ?

Comment: Your new, blank single-view project also works on Simulator but you get the errors when building for device?

Comment: @DonMag Yes exactly ! And it even fails if I select Generic iOS Device and hit Product > Build

Comment: Did you happen to recently right-click on a UIKit object / method and select "jump to definition" -- which took you to the SDK header file?

Comment: @DonMag Just tried, it works well (showing SDK header file)

Comment: Whoops... go to your ViewController.h file, select `<UIKit/UIKit.h>`, right-click and select jump to definition... Look at the first 25 or so lines... does it look exactly like this? https://pastebin.com/CPzgGCk7

Comment: @DonMag Yes it does…

Comment: hmmm... I saw something similar once... the dev had used "jump to definition" to check a UIKit method signature, and had inadvertently deleted something there... Maybe check the SDK headers folder and see if any .h files have a modified date of today?

Comment: @DonMag Just checked, none of .h files have been modified… Correct me if I'm wrong but I think if that developer did that, it wouldn't work on simulator too isn't it ? (Thanks a lot for your help !)

Comment: Does your `ViewController.h` file import `UIKit`?

Comment: @AnthoPak - well, there are two SDKs... iPhoneSimulator.sdk and iPhoneOS.sdk and each has a set of Frameworks, inside of which are all the header files. If *one* is corrupt (for some reason), that could explain why you don't get errors when building for Simulator but do get errors when building for Device.

Comment: @Koen Yes, it's the exact same project generated by Xcode

Comment: @DonMag Oh yes, you're absolutely right ! Nevertheless, I'm *pretty* sure that I haven't modified any file from `UIKit` framework…

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :** 
I've encounter the same bug again today. As reinstalling `Xcode` is pretty long, I've tried to just replace the `UIKit.framework` (which is located here : `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`) which was the principal culprit. I took it from another `Xcode 9` instance that I have already installed. As of now, I keep the non-corrupted framework in a safe place, just in case it happened again. About what could corrupt the framework, I really don't know, probably `Xcode 9` bug...

**INITIAL ANSWER :** 
**I've solved this bug by *simply* reinstalling `Xcode` totally.**

My clue was that everything was working well with my version 9.1 of `Xcode`, so I was wondering if the bug comes from 9.2 version or just the `Xcode` instance. And reinstalling totally fixed the bug, so it was just the instance.

Xcode somehow have been corrupted for some reason. As frameworks (including `UIKit`), are included in the app, there's a lot of assumption that the corruption was coming from here.

Hope this can help anybody to avoid wasting time as I did !

Comment: +1: Glad to hear you’ve found a temporary solution but please log this with Apple (even if it sounds like something is touching your SDK): https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @RoboticCat Thanks for your suggestion. I'm indeed going to add a bug report for this.